# an indefinite integral $\int \frac{dx}{\sin{x}\sqrt{\sin(2x+\alpha)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

In the following integration:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sin{x}\sqrt{\sin(2x+\alpha)}}$$

My attempt is:

I substituted $\sin(2x+\alpha) = t$.

And got $2\cos(2x+\alpha)~dx =dt$.

But after that got stuck.

Can somebody help me.

Comment: where did you get this integral

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2F%28sin%28x%29*sqrt%28sin%28x%29%2Ba%29%29+dx&x=0&y=0) yields an ugly result.

Comment: Wolfram is not having this one... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F(sin(x)sqrt(sin(2x%2Ba)))+dx

Comment: This is in my book

Comment: No textbook would give an example as challenging as this on purpose

Comment: What is the book? I've seen multiple users posting screenshots like this (there was a rash of them involving ridiculous limits), that clearly have a watermark and, presumably, are from the same book.

Comment: Noticed that as well pjs36...

Comment: The answer given in the book is http://i.imgur.com/oYu3Y4S.jpg

Comment: @pjs36 that book is available online thats why

Comment: What is the book's name?

Comment: use the addition formulas to simplify the square root term

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner but in addition formula there is no squared term then how can we simplify it

Comment: i meant $$\sin(2x+\alpha)=\sin(2x)\cos(\alpha)+\cos(2x)\sin(\alpha)$$

Comment: I don't trust mathematics texts not written with LaTeX...

Comment: Beautiful formatting ^^!

Comment: Maple V (yes, I'm a luddite) gives an answer if I set $\alpha = 1$, but it's more than 4 pages of square roots of cosines and such.  And I spot several occurrences of EllipticPi and and EllipticF in there.  This ain't your grandma's integral. I'd set $\alpha=0$ and then you'll have a nice, challenging exercise.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner this is what I have done in my attempt

Comment: Which book did you encounter this integral from?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Please reconsider this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin(2x+A)=\sin2x\cos A+\cos2x\sin A$

$=\sin^2x\{2\cos A\cot x+(\cot^2x-1)\sin A\}$

Put $-\cot x=v$ to find $$I=\int\dfrac{dx}{\sin x\sqrt{\sin(2x+A)}}=(\text{sign of} \sin x)\int\dfrac{dv}{\sqrt{(v^2-1)\sin A-2v\cos A}}$$

**Case**$\#1:$ For $\sin A>0,$  $$\sqrt{\sin A}\cdot I=(\text{sign of} \sin x)\int\dfrac{dv}{\sqrt{(v^2-1)-2v\cot A}}$$

Now $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dv}{\sqrt{(v^2-1)-2v\cot A}}=\int\dfrac{dv}{\sqrt{(v-\cot A)^2-\csc^2A}}$

**Case**$\#2:$ For $\sin A<0,$  $$\sqrt{-\sin A}\cdot I=(\text{sign of} \sin x)\int\dfrac{dv}{\sqrt{-(v^2-1)+2v\cot A}}$$

Now $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v^2+2v\cot A}}=\int\dfrac{dv}{\sqrt{\csc^2A-(v-\cot A)^2}}$

Can yo take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i didnot understand why you broke it down into cases.please clarify a bit.

Comment: @navinstudent, As we are dealing with real Calculus, we need to be careful about the sign under radical i.e.$\sqrt{}$.  First of all, $$\sqrt{\sin^2x\{2\cos A\cot x+(\cot^2x-1)\sin A\}}=\sqrt{\sin^2x}\cdot\sqrt{2\cos A\cot x+(\cot^2x-1)\sin A}$$  Now $\sqrt{\sin^2x}=|\sin x|=$sign of$(\sin x)\cdot\sin x$

Comment: @navinstudent, 
Again, $2\cos A\cot x+(\cot^2x-1)\sin A=\sin x\{\cot^2x-1+2\cot A\cot x\}$

If $\sin A>0,$

$$\sqrt{2\cos A\cot x+(\cot^2x-1)\sin A}=\sqrt{\sin A}\cdot\sqrt{\cot^2x-1+2\cot A\cot x}$$  and if $\sin A<0,$

$$\sqrt{2\cos A\cot x+(\cot^2x-1)\sin A}=\sqrt{-\sin A}\cdot\sqrt{-(\cot^2x-1)-2\cot A\cot x}$$

Comment: Excellent i used to neglect the signs often.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sin x \sqrt{\sin 2x \cos a + \cos 2x \sin a}}$$ which is same as $$\int \frac{dx}{\sin x \sqrt{\sin 2x} \sqrt{ \cos a + \cot 2x \sin a}}$$ Now let $t=\cos a+\cot 2x \sin a$.Then $dt=-2cosec ^2 2x \sin a dx$.So that i could rewrite the integral as $$-\frac{√2}{\sin a} \int \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}(\cos x)^{3/2} dt}{√t}$$ I then tried to go in for integration by parts but that seemed too lengthy and cumbersome.