# Find limit of $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of the following sequence:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}$$

I can transform the above to:

$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2-x}}$$

But I can't seem to prove that the term is diminishing and that its superlum is $1$ (which would prove the limit). Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: You're going about it the right way. You can, for instance, divide top and bottom by $x$, while factoring in $x$ inside the square root at the bottom.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597177/find-the-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx2x-sqrtx2-x?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write your limit in the form $$\frac{2x}{x\left(\sqrt{1+1/x}+\sqrt{1-1/x}\right)}$$

Comment: Sonhard Graubner Thank you! Duh....

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

You are on right way.

Take x common from terms in denominator.